# How to compute a value from two MySQL database columns for use in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I have a query that starts like...

```
SELECT session_id, time, quantity, teacher, sum(time+(quantity*60*60*60)) AS end FROM my_table WHERE end > 1582214400
```

I am getting a PDO exception...

```
column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'end' in 'where clause'
```

Why is PDO/MySQL giving me this error?  What is the correct syntax to compute **end** so I can use it in the WHERE clause?

Comment: In addition to the answers, `end` is a sql key word. You should change your key word for avoid possible errors.

Comment: As is `time`, which is a function name and a data type. But neither `end` nor `time` are **reserved**. If they should be used as identifier is an opinion and off topic here.

Comment: Did any of the answers meet your need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an alias from `select` in `where` clause. Use `having` instead as follows:

```
SELECT session_id, time, quantity, teacher, sum(time+(quantity*60*60*60)) AS end FROM my_table having end > 1582214400
```

Answer (score 0):

Jens is right on target that you can't use the alias `end` like the way you did. There are a couple other ways you can write the query also. Since that was too long for a comment, I added an answer.

Here's an alternate way of writing the query. Notice that I have explicitly used `group by` clause.

```
SELECT
  session_id,
  time,
  quantity,
  teacher,
  sum(time+(quantity*60*60*60)) AS end
FROM my_table
GROUP BY
  session_id,
  time,
  quantity,
  teacher 
HAVING sum(time+(quantity*60*60*60)) > 1582214400
```

or you could use a subquery, which could be inefficient.

```
SELECT * FROM (

  SELECT
    session_id,
    time,
    quantity,
    teacher,
    sum(time+(quantity*60*60*60)) AS end
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY
    session_id,
    time,
    quantity,
    teacher 

) main
WHERE end > 1582214400
```